# Change subplot size in python matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, figure

I would like to change the size of the *subplot* when I use Python's matplotlib. I already know how to change the size of the *figure*, however, how does one go about changing the size of the corresponding subplots themselves? This has remained somewhat elusive in my googling. Thanks.

(For example, given a figure where we have 2x4 subplots. I want to make the subplots within the figure occupy more area).

Answer (score 4):

You can also play with the axis size. 
http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

set_position() can be used to change width and height of your axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 1.1 , box.height * 1.1])
```

Comment: May you please give an example illustrating this?

Comment: I added a quick example. Not tested though. I hope it can help you :)

Comment: Thaks, I had been looking for something like this for long. However it has a strange behavior when I have one plot from imshow and the other from plt, and the figure is resized, as proportions are not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust), e.g.

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

g = sns.factorplot(x='sex',y='age',hue='class',data=titanic,
                  kind='bar',ci=None,legend=False)
g.fig.suptitle('Oversized Plot',size=16)
plt.legend(loc='best')
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=1.05,bottom=-0.05,left=-0.05,right=1.05)
```

Results in this monstrosity:

[image]