# Changing subplot size for displaying ellipse correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I'm trying to plot the confidence ellipse for uniformly distributed points. When plotting the ellipse and the scatter plot using Matplotlib, I find that a portion of the ellipse is clipped by the subplot. I tried implementing other solutions suggested here on SO, given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863262/change-subplot-size-in-python-matplotlib), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510831/changing-size-of-matplotlib-subplots), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770735/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-with-subplots) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots). but am not able to correct the displayed plot.

How do I change the size of this subplot in order to correctly and completely display the ellipse?

Code for generating ellipse: [multidimensional confidence intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301071/multidimensional-confidence-intervals)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def eigsorted(cov):
    vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
    order = vals.argsort()[::-1]
    return vals[order], vecs[:,order]

nstd = 2

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 5))
#ax = plt.subplots(111)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
test1 = np.random.uniform(40, 60, 1000)
test2 = np.random.uniform(100, 120, 1000)
cov = np.cov(test1, test2)
vals, vecs = eigsorted(cov)
theta = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*vecs[:,0][::-1]))
w, h = 2 * nstd * np.sqrt(vals)
ell = Ellipse(xy=(np.mean(test1), np.mean(test2)),
              width=w, height=h,
              angle=theta, color='black')
ell.set_facecolor('none')
ax.add_artist(ell)
plt.scatter(test1, test2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The ellipse is a patch. Use `ax.add_patch(ell)` to add it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Any ideas with regards to a similar question where adding the patch does not fit the ellipse correctly in the plot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289316/changing-plot-size-in-matplotlib-to-fit-ellipses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest rightly commented, a patch needed to be added for displaying the ellipse correctly. Updating the code below for future reference of others.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def eigsorted(cov):
    vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
    order = vals.argsort()[::-1]
    return vals[order], vecs[:,order]

nstd = 2

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 5))
#ax = plt.subplots(111)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
test1 = np.random.uniform(40, 60, 1000)
test2 = np.random.uniform(100, 120, 1000)
cov = np.cov(test1, test2)
vals, vecs = eigsorted(cov)
theta = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*vecs[:,0][::-1]))
w, h = 2 * nstd * np.sqrt(vals)
ell = Ellipse(xy=(np.mean(test1), np.mean(test2)),
              width=w, height=h,
              angle=theta, color='black')
ell.set_facecolor('none')

#Corrected code for displaying ellipse correctly
ax.add_patch(ell)

plt.scatter(test1, test2)
plt.show()
```